# How to create a new dicom image with annotations from other?

Tags: python, pydicom

I would like to create two pydicom file from one. But I can't save file in *.dcm format with annotations.

```
import pydicom
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files
# read the dicom file
ds = pydicom.dcmread(test_image_fps[0])
# find the shape of your pixel data
shape = ds.pixel_array.shape
# get the half of the x dimension. For the y dimension use shape[0]
half_x = int(shape[1] / 2)
# slice the halves
# [first_axis, second_axis] so [:,:half_x] means slice all from first axis, slice 0 to half_x from second axis
data  = ds.pixel_array[:, :half_x]
print('The image has {} x {}'.format(data.shape[0],
                                        data.shape[1]))

# print the image information given in the dataset
print(data)
data.save_as("/my/path/after.dcm")
```

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save_as
```

Answer (score 0):

Info on this can be foud in the [pydicom documentation](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/working_with_pixel_data.html).
Remark on "your" ;) code: `data  = ds.pixel_array[:, :half_x]` assigns a view of the numpy.ndarray that is ds.pixel_array to `data`. Calling `data.save_as()` expectedly fails because that is an attribute of `ds` not `data`. As per the documentation you need to write to the `ds.PixelData` attribute like so:

```py
ds.PixelData = data.tobytes() # where data is a numpy.ndarray or a view of an numpy.ndarray

# if the shape of your pixel data changes ds.Rows and ds.Columns must be updated,
# otherwise calls to ds.pixel_array.shape will fail
ds.Rows = 512 # update with correct number of rows
ds.Columns = 512 # update with the correct number of columns
ds.save_as("/my/path/after.dcm")
```